# Adding cloninginfo property to arm template deployment slot resource breaks setting user defined managed identity on deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I discovered something, and I think it's a bug in ARM templates.

I have a template that creates an app service, and creates a deployment slot. Now I wanted to make sure that the deployment slot cloned the appsettings from the parent app service, so I used the `cloningInfo` node to set the source app service for the clone. But once I did that, setting the user defined managed identity on the deployment slot stopped working, while it is present in the template. My (simplified) template:

```
resources: [
{
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "MyAppservice",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "app",
      "identity": {
        "type": "userAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "<some id>": {}
         }
      }
},

{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "['MyAppservice','/secondslot')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'MyAppservice')]"
  ],
  "kind": "app",
  "identity": {
    "type": "userAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {
      "<some id>": {}
    },
   "properties": {
      "cloningInfo": {
      "sourceWebAppId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'MyAppservice')]"
    }
   }
  }

]
```

So when I deploy a template using the above basis, the user defined managed identity is not set on the deployment slot. When I remove the cloningInfo property, the user defined managed identity IS set, but the app settings of the parent app service are not copied.

Am I doing someting wrong here or is this a bug? I know that (for some reason) it is by design that use defined managed identities are not copied to deployment slots, so I would assume that when setting it manually while cloning from an existing app service, the cloning setting would not overwrite the user defined managed identity.

Comment: This seems to be an issue after I tested. I have reported in appropriate channel.

Comment: @krishg thanks for testing. What channel have you reported it to, and can I follow the progress anywhere?

Comment: Reported internally to App Service team, so not available in any public channel. If you have any Azure support plan, you can go ahead also to create a ticket. Otherwise, let's wait for my update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acknowledged that this is an issue currently where if cloning Info set, it's ignoring rest of the payload. Until it's fixed, workaround is to have 2 separate updates (one for cloning and one for MSI).

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue?  I was trying to clone a webapp and change the tags.  I haven't been able to find any way to make this happen.